# How do I make this so the text doesn't overlap the icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have an html input and a font awesome icon. I don't want to limit the amount of text a user enters. Rather, I'd like to make it so that the text doesn't overlap .fa-comment-o...any extra text will just be hidden (not cut-off, just hidden). The best example I can give is when you enter something in google the text doesn't overlap the microphone, nor do they cut if off (they use an image whereas I am using a font icon).

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stpra123/mxw323ec/)

```
<div id="container">
    <input id="input"  value="This is some really long text that will almost certainly not fit within the text box. What I'd like to do is not bleed beyond the comment icon."/>
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
</div>


#input{
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: -30px;

}

.fa-comment-o{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following changes to your code `padding-right:30px` Beware when your increase your `padding` your width increases.

```
#input{
    width: 270px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    padding-right:30px;

}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/mxw323ec/2/)

Comment: +1. Or maybe use `box-sizing: border-box` to make padding a part of the box width.

Comment: Yes you can do that too. But older versions of ie don't support that.